# DAX formula for Outlier Detection with PERCENTILEX.INC

Tags: dax

I am unable to get this DAX to work. This is the correct formula, however, I am missing a key step or something cause the DAX doesn't produce the result. Where am I going wrong in my code?

```
    Measure = 
    var Q3 = PERCENTILEX.INC(ALL(Analytics[Users]),Analytics[Users],.75)
    var Q1 = PERCENTILEX.INC(ALL(Analytics[Users]),Analytics[Users],.25)
    var iqr = Q3-Q1
    var lower = Q1-iqr*1.5
    var upper = Q3+iqr*1.5
    return
      SWITCH(TRUE(),
         SELECTEDVALUE(Analytics[Users])>=upper,"high",
         SELECTEDVALUE(Analytics[Users])<=lower ,"low",
         BLANK()
```

Here is some sample data:

```
Day Index   Users
1/1/2020    335
1/2/2020    1131
1/3/2020    1094
1/4/2020    393
1/5/2020    22
1/6/2020    1380
1/7/2020    1607
1/8/2020    1578
1/9/2020    1640
1/10/2020   1368
1/11/2020   477
1/12/2020   634
1/13/2020   1812
1/14/2020   1840
1/15/2020   1802
1/16/2020   1708
1/17/2020   1386
1/18/2020   420
1/19/2020   544
1/20/2020   1527
1/21/2020   1799
1/22/2020   1938
1/23/2020   3000
1/24/2020   1570
1/25/2020   546
1/26/2020   660
```

Comment: Can you share a sample of your dataset and what's the expected result?

Comment: The outlier should show for the 22 and the 3000

Comment: For the data sample you provided it seems like you don't have outliers. The `upper bound` is 3,375.5 and the `lower bound` is -1,116.5